# How do you search over multiple fields in a Django model

Tags: django, django-queryset

PsuedoCode for Model called Person:

```
id         =  primary key
first_name =  charField...
last_name  =  charField...
```

My Query:

```
queryset_list = Person.objects.filter(Q(id__icontains=id_filter) & (Q(first_name__icontains=name_filter) | Q(last_name__icontains=name_filter)))
```

id_filter and name_filter come from a form. If name_filter is "Betty", then the person named Betty Bee shows up.
However, my problem is if name_filter is "Betty B", nothing will show up (understandably). How would I do a search similar in effect to:

```
Q( (first_name + last_name)__icontains=name_filter )?
```

EDIT- It seems like more detail would have helped as I slightly simplified the problem. I'm using a SQLite DB locally and a MySQL DB on production. Also, I'm actually working with a Student model that is separate from the person model.

```
Based on the best answer so far:
students.filter(Q(id__icontains=id_filter)).extra(
                where=['lower(concat(base_Base_person.first_name, " ", base_Base_person.last_name)) like %s'],
                params=['%%%s%%' % name_filter]
            )
```

The query works! Yay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra).

Query for **postgres**:

```
# || is string concatenation in postgres
# query = "Betty B"
queryset_list = Person.objects.extra(
    where=['first_name || ' ' || last_name ilike %s']
    params=['%%%s%%' % query]
)
```

Result query will be similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM appname_person WHERE first_name ||' '|| last_name ilike 'Betty B';
```

For **MySql** this query should work:

```
# concat using for string concatenation in Mysql;
queryset_list = Person.objects.extra(
    where=['lower(concat(first_name," ",last_name)) like %s']
    params=['%%%s%%' % query]
)
```

Comment: I'm using SQLite in dev and MySQL in production. I think extra may be the right way to go but I get a syntax error:    

near "ilike": syntax error         


I have added a comma after the where clause and before params...will keep trying, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful response, Would you know how to do the equivalent of a __ (double underscore) in an the extra command?      where=['lower(concat(base_person__first_name," ",base_person__last_name)) like %s']

Comment: @Alf you cant do such query with filter lookups(__) but you can combine filter and extra

Comment: instead of __, I used the <app>_<model>.<column> trick and it seemed to work :)